# How to work with dates and a .dat file

Tags: bash, awk

I have this `.dat` file:

```
933|Mahinda|Perera|male|1989-12-03|2010-03-17T13:32:10.447+0000|192.248.2.123|Firefox
1129|Carmen|Lepland|female|1984-02-18|2010-02-28T04:39:58.781+0000|81.25.252.111|Internet Explorer
4194|Hồ Chí|Do|male|1988-10-14|2010-03-17T22:46:17.657+0000|103.10.89.118|Internet Explorer
8333|Chen|Wang|female|1980-02-02|2010-03-15T10:21:43.365+0000|1.4.16.148|Internet Explorer
8698|Chen|Liu|female|1982-05-29|2010-02-21T08:44:41.479+0000|14.103.81.196|Firefox
8853|Albin|Monteno|male|1986-04-09|2010-03-19T21:52:36.860+0000|178.209.14.40|Internet Explorer
10027|Ning|Chen|female|1982-12-08|2010-02-22T17:59:59.221+0000|1.2.9.86|Firefox
1099511628908|Wei|Chen|female|1985-08-02|2010-05-24T20:52:26.582+0000|27.98.244.108|Firefox
1099511633435|Jack|Smith|male|1981-04-19|2010-05-26T03:45:11.772+0000|50.72.193.218|Internet Explorer
1099511635042|Gyorgy|Kiss|male|1984-09-14|2010-05-16T22:57:41.808+0000|91.137.244.86|Chrome
```

And I want to choose all lines between two dates. For example I want to take all persons born since *1980-01-01* until *1987-01-01*

I'm trying:

```
if [ $1 == "--born-since" ] && [ $3 == "--born-until" ] && [ $5 == "-f" ]; then
    since=$(date -d $2 +"%Y%m%d")
    until=$(date -d $4 +"%Y%m%d")
    awk -F '|' -v UNTIL="$until" SINCE="$since" '($5 < UNTIL)($5 > SINCE){print}' $6
fi
```

But this doesn't seems right.

Even if I try to choose only born since "date", this doesn't work:

```
if [ $1 == "--born-since" ] && [ $3 == "-f" ]; then
    since=$(date -d $2 +"%Y%m%d")
    awk -F '|' -v SINCE="$since" '($5 > SINCE){print}' $4
fi
```

Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:

```
since=$(date -d $2 +"%Y%m%d")
until=$(date -d $4 +"%Y%m%d")
```

that is, your defined format is something like `19891203`

However in your file, the date format is: `1989-12-03`. You cannot compare them.

You can change the output format in your `date` command, so that make it same as the date format in your dat file.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that this is probably due to different time formats. Try using this:

```
awk -F "|" -v since=$2 -v until=$4 '
    function dattimestamp(s) {
        return mktime(gensub("-", " ", "g", s) " 00 00 00")
    }

    function argtimestamp(s) {
        return mktime(substr(since,0,4) " " substr(since,4,2) " " substr(since,6,2) " 00 00 00")
    }

    BEGIN {since=argtimestamp(since); until=argtimestamp(until)} 

    dattimestamp($5)>since && dattimestamp($5)<until {print}'
```

This will handle the different time formats of the dat-file and the arguments and convert them both to epoch-based times, that are easy to compare.

There is room for improvement in that it runs the `dattimestamp` function twice, while only once is really needed.